# How did Alfred know where Bruce was after all those years?

Tags: plot-explanation, batman-begins

In *Batman Begins*, after Bruce is done training and decides to head back to Gotham, Alfred shows up in a plane to pick him up. How did Alfred know where he was? Did Bruce have a phone to call him or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bruce is highly resourceful. He did cross continents using nothing but his wits, twice (firstly when he ran off in *Batman Begins* and when he returned in *The Dark Knight Rises*).

Considering who he is along with the above, does one really have to suspend their disbelief when considering how he notified Alfred of his location, considering **EVERYTHING** else that happens in the film and its two sequels?

TL;DR - He asked someone if he could use their phone and reversed the charge.

Comment: Also know as ["collect call"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collect_call) - the receiver of the call pays for it. Or he just emailed him. Or he left an anon post in some BBS elsewhere. But this answer should notice that it was not shown how he did it. If it was, please add a reference.

Comment: It was not shown exactly how he did it so I cannot show a reference - I can only surmise from what was shown that it would have not been problematic for Bruce to have let Alfred know in some way or another. The TL;DR was supposed to be a joke, evidently not a very good one.

Comment: Nothing against common sense, but the stack likes objectivity. If your answer is based on speculation, it must be clear.  =^.^=

Comment: I have not speculated on anything with the exception that Bruce is resourceful and considering how the character is portrayed across the 3 films I am confident that his resourcefulness is an objective perspective.